# Assigning print media query for the body using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have a web page and have a bootstrap modal on click of a button. I have written the print media query to print the content of the modal. But if I put the media query in css, the modal data is printing just fine but it blocks the parent page from getting printed using (cntrl+P) when the modal is not open. Is there a way where I can have both the functionalities for printing the parent page and the modal. Is there a way to dynamically attach the print media query to only print the modal content not affecting the parent page printing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change all of the selectors in the media query to only apply when `<body>` has a specific class (`body.HasModal .SomeClass`).

You can then simply apply that class whenever the model is open.

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal which opens on click of a link .. I am not sure how would you apply that on the body